# Set minimum order value and enable checkout

Tags: addtocart

I'm setting up a site that sells variable products, priced by area. I need to set a minimum order value to cover production costs.

I can set a minimum order value that does not allow the order to proceed and makes the customer buy more product but that isn't what I need. I can set a base price for the product with the area calculation added on to that, but that also isn't quite right.

I need the minimum basket value to be set at £50 until the product value exceeds this and can go on to reflect the size / cost of the product accordingly.

```
eg. product calculates at £5, basket = £50

product calculates at £30, basket = £50

product calculates at £56, basket = £56

product calculates at £120, basket = £120
```

I'm new to Magento and any help is very much appreciated, please be kind!